# while running hive script getting error Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag

Tags: hive, cloudera

```
`select distinct cast(date_format(A.created_ts ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as char(20)) as created_date
,A.c360_id
,A.external_id
,A.business_name
,A.first_name
,A.last_name
,A.email
,A.phone
,A.address_id
,A.address_type
,A.Address_Line1
,A.Address_Line2
,A.Address_Line3
,A.city
,A.state
,A.postal_code
,A.country
,A.created_ts
,A.ext_org_code
,cast(' ' as char(01)) as guild_created_ts
,cast(' ' as char(01)) as guild_last_modified_ts
,cast(' ' as char(01)) as residence_created_ts
,cast(' ' as char(01)) as residence_last_modified_ts
,current_timestamp() as transaction_date
,cast('YES' as char(03)) as Opt_out_flag
from
(select c360_id,acxiom_opt_out_deceased_flag,deceased_data_suppression_flag,large_prison_suppression_flag from SA
where acxiom_opt_out_deceased_flag is true or deceased_data_suppression_flag is true or large_prison_suppression_flag is true
and (created_ts > (select current_run_time from delta_run_time where job_type = 'customer') or
last_modified_ts > (select current_run_time from delta_run_time where job_type = 'customer'))) s join
(select *,row_number() over (partition by c360_id order by edsr_key desc) as rank from SE ')  A
on A.c360_id = s.c360_id where rank =1 and A.ext_org_code = '30' `
```

i am joining two tables for my job in production and it has been running fine for a few months and lately this is failing for last 5 to 6 days with below error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag

can you someone explain when can we expect this error

Comment: can you pls add your SQL? What suddenly changed - like os patching /update/config changed/version changed ?

Comment: @KoushikRoy i have added the sql

Comment: Have you ever tried running it in hive? I can see some syntax issues in line right before last line.